# Maven Multimodule project issue?

Tags: java, maven

Hi I have multimodule maven project something like this..

> parent
>
> 1. Core
> 2. Web

and my **Web** project depend on **Core** project classes so i added **Core** project as a dependency in **Web** project **pom.xml** file. 
But from inside eclipse when i am running **Web** project the lib directory does not contain **Core-project.jar** file in **class-path** so project not running. How can resolve this issue?..Plugin I used in my **Web Projec** **Pom.xml** file..

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

And i am using Tomcat6 Server.

this Dependency tag in my Web Project pom.xml File...

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.csdc</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And When i run web project from inside Eclipse i am not getting **core.jar** in this path....

> workspace_maven.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\web\WEB-INF\lib

Anyone got any such issue .If yes please let me know how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Show the complete pom's and we might be able to help otherwise we can only guess..

Comment: Which Pom U will want to see Parent or Child pom?

Answer (score 1):

Under Eclipse : you do not need to have your core.jar in your classpath. Check your librairies (web->properties->java build path->librairies), you should see your core folder and not your core.jar.

Make sure that "resolve workspace dependencies" is checked in your maven build target.

Answer (score 1):

Install the m2e and m2e-wtp plugins for eclipse. m2e-wtp handles web projects and tomcat. You don't need the plugins sections of your pom that you've documented in the question.

For maven to work with projects in eclipse you need to ensure that the parent project is at the same level as the child projects and the pom of the parent project is like below

```
<modules>
    <module>../project1</module>
    <module>../project2</module>
</modules>
```

Unfortunately this is the only way to get maven to work correctly in eclipse and jenkins for multi-module builds.

Comment: <modules>
  <module>web</module>
 <module>core</module>
 </modules>
This is in My Parent pom.xml entry which is looking ok according to your suggestion.But still the core project jar not in classpath of web project.Thats why  when i am running web project from inside 
eclipse tomcat not copying core.jar file inside path i edited in question.

Comment: try <modules> <module>../web</module> <module>../core</module> </modules>

Comment: But the previous comment i did.this entry added by maven itself.

Comment: @sfk I'm working with Maven and Eclipse on multimodules projects with the parent project being at one level on top of the child, and I didn't get any issue until now. Which issues are caused by such structure?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache maven-release-plugin doesn't suppport it now. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/

Comment: @PaulV According to the first link, there is an issue with the maven-release-plugin for the flat structure, not for the hierarchical structure. Also, this issue has been solved. So, as I said, I'm working with Maven and Eclipse on multimodules projects with the parent project being at one level on top of the child (i.e. hierarchical), and I didn't get any issue until now.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache nice to see this thread is alive. Thought I'd mention that my answer specified 'and jenkins' and was my experience from over 2 yrs ago. It might be different now

Comment: Well. I could not use maven-release-plugin with Flat folder layout and Perforce. Maybe it is maven SCM plugin issue.

Answer (score 0):

Install the correct set of plugins and configure them correctly.

If you need a more detailed answer, you should give us more information what you tried to achieve, which plugins you use, what kind of web server, how you deploy, whether you use Maben to deploy or the Eclipse WTP, etc.

**[EDIT]** You won't see anything in project/WEB-INF/lib when you start the project in Eclipse - there is no point putting anything in there because this folder isn't used.

Instead, you probably deploy the project to a web server. There are plugins for Eclipse which can do that (i.e. start a web server, deploy your project into it) but since you don't mention how exactly you "start" the project inside of Eclipse, which version of Eclipse you're using and which buttons you click, how you configured Eclipse, etc. it's really hard to help you.

Comment: The information you gave isn't what we need. See my updated answer.

Comment: I already configure Tomcat Server in Eclipse and when I am Doing RIght Click on project->Run On Server then Eclipse running my project in Tomcat Server .And Eclipse Version  : Helios Service Release 2

Comment: If i am doing mvn clean install and deploying war in my tomcat(Outside of eclipse) everything work fine but when i am RUnning project from inside eclipse ,Right Click on Project->Run On Server then it is not working because only core project jar not in classpath.

Comment: Do you see the core (either as project or JAR) in "Maven Dependencies" in Web project?

Comment: yes it is in my web project pom.xml file can i post the code for that

Comment: But do you see it in the "Project Explorer" when you open the item "Maven Dependencies"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19276/discussion-between-subodh-and-aaron-digulla)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear that this is what you are looking for, but the jars won't appear under your lib directory in eclipse because they are in your repository.

My version of eclipse has a 'maven' menu when I right click on the project. If yours does too then make sure that you have 'Enable Maven Nature' selected. This will make a small M appear next to the project name and a new folder in the project, which contains all of the dependencies listed in your pom.

Comment: All jar are there which are coming from repository only the core project jar not in classpath of web project.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to web project build path -> Libraries - Add variable -> Configure Variables -> New -> Enter Name as M2_REPO and Path as C:\Users\usernmee.m2\repository and click Ok. 
All the dependencies will configured in the project build path. So no compilation error in web projecct.
2.Maven project need to take war and deploy it in any web container(tomcat,etc).

Comment: I think you did not get my point issue is only module jar not other jar.As i asked i have multi module maven project. and My web project added my java project as a dependency and this Java project jar not added in the classpath and other jar file are there which are coming from repository

Comment: Yes, module jar should be available in your local repository if it is completed successfully, and the same jar will be available in target folder of the same project.

Comment: That is fine dear i am able to run web.war from tomcat but issue is that when i am running project from eclipse then i am getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

Check the war in your target directory after running mvn clean package. If it is missing there, check the scope of your dependency for "Core" in your pom.xml for "Web", make sure that it is not provided or test.

It sounds like from your pom fragment that you are using mvn eclipse:eclipse (which you shouldn't be anymore), instead use the m2eclipse plugin: http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse.

Comment: I am using eclipse plugin inside the eclipse